# Whether TABLOCK will improve the performance of BULK INSERT or not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I just wonder whether TABLOCK will improve the performance of BULK INSERT or not?

Based on the first answer in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165966/how-does-one-investigate-the-performance-of-a-bulk-insert-statement, it seems that TABLOCK will.

Based on the official document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, it said " A table can be loaded concurrently by multiple clients if the table has no indexes and TABLOCK is specified." But for my case, only one session need to bulk insert the data into the database, so it seems that I do not need to specify TABLOCK at all.

I have asked this question on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a957cd37-ec96-4beb-8a4b-03d783c7f91e/whether-tablock-will-improve-the-performance-of-bulk-insert-or-not?forum=transactsql but not get a satisfactory answer, so I have to repost the question here.

Thanks

Comment: For the second link, in the official docs, it also said, tablock optimizes the insert. Another benefit is, that users still can select the table, but no one can insert, which prevents some race-conditions...

Comment: You have an answer from Erland Sommarskog on that link, Erland is one of the most knowledgeable MVPs and he's not sure wether you will benefit from the TABLOCK hint.  I guess you will just have to test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

TABLOCK specifies that a table-level lock is acquired for the duration of the bulk-import operation. A table can be loaded concurrently by multiple clients if the table has no indexes and TABLOCK is specified. By default, locking behavior is determined by the table option table lock on bulk load. Holding a lock for the duration of the bulk-import operation reduces lock contention on the table, in some cases can significantly improve performance.

If your data insert into table with only one session table lock have not any benefit for you but when many session can insert data into your table the table lock can reduce lock contention in your process. but when your table have table lock another session can not access to table.